# Download bank statement file from online banking website with webclient

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I've been trying to download bank statement in OFX format using webclient like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace DownloadBankStatement
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new system.net.CookieAwareWebClient())
            {
                var LoginValues = new NameValueCollection
                {
                    {"newCardNumber","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"},
                    {"pswPassword","XXXX"}
                };
                client.UploadValues("https://www.cibconline.cibc.com/olbtxn/authentication/SignOn.cibc", "POST", LoginValues
                var PostValues = new NameValueCollection
                {
                    {"selectedAccount","XXXXX,XXXXXXX"},
                    {"selectedCriteria","2"},
                    {"fromDateMonth","2"},
                    {"fromDateDay","7"},
                    {"fromDateYear","2017"},
                    {"toDateMonth","2"},
                    {"toDateDay","7"},
                    {"toDateYear","2017"},
                    {"selectedFMSPackage","3"}
                };
                byte[] Statement = client.UploadValues("https://www.cibconline.cibc.com/olbtxn/accounts/TransactionDownload2.cibc", "POST", PostValues);
                File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Statement.aso", Statement);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();          
        }        
    }
}

namespace system.net
{
    public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

        public CookieAwareWebClient()
        {
            this.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        }

        public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer cookieContainer)
        {
            this.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request == null) return base.GetWebRequest(address);
            request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except the response I get is the web page which contains the second form where I set the bank statement parameters.

I examined the POST details which shows:

Content-disposition:attachment; filename=cibc.aso
Content-Length:20052
Content-Type:application/vnd.accpac.simply.aso

When I POST the form manually using IE there's always a popup window asking me to either save it or opening it dorectly, but when I use Chrome to do the same no question is asked and the file is directly downloaded.

So what would be the right way to save the cibc.aso file which is obviously an attachment here? Your feedback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the browser settings. In chrome settings, under downloads; there is a checkbox to tic "Ask where to save each file before downloading".